# How to use Jwts to generate Jwt Token ? Can anyone share me code..?

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
private String dogenerateToken(Map<String, Object> map, String username) {
    return null;
}
```

I am having only null method...Can you write logic to generate jwt token...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below logic. Before that get the username and password from the user and authenticate it ...and send the authenticationto the generate token method and generate token like this.

```
 public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        Details user = (Details) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(null).setSubject(user.getUsername()).setSubject(user.getEmail())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + tokenExpirationTime))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey).compact();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Santil, Thanks for you logic. Its working fine for creating JWT token.